# iOS Navigation Bar - I would like to set the title in Navigation bar with a dynamic value

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

iOS Navigation Bar - I would like to set the title in Navigation bar with a dynamic value.

Title could be Coffee (xxx cups)

The value of xxx is changed dynamically based on user input.

Thank you.

Comment: Hey Tom, what have you tried so far? What isn't working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somewhere in your view controller code:

```
self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Coffee (%d cups)", self.numberOfCupsOfCoffee];
```

Without more details, I can't be more precise.